# PHP mail() как отправить с конкретного адреса

Tags: php, email, текст, sendmail, localhost

Вот лежит у меня на localhost'е сайт PHP. Я решил добавить функцию восстановления пароля путем отсылки сообщения на почту. В интернете нашел функцию `mail($to,$subject,$text)`. Насколько я понял - на хостингах оно со спец. адреса отправляется. А как мне отправить его с конкретного адреса, не заливая сайт на хостинг?Со своего локального сервера? Если просто так отсылаю себе на почту - сообщение не приходит.

Comment: Думаю, [этот ответ](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-use-phpmailer/134686) подойдёт. Просто исключите ненужные пункты из объяснения

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Я застопорился на 2 шаге - решистрации в файл-менеджере: что бы я не ввел жалуется "Log in details are not correct."

Comment: @Nezerix зачем вам регистрироваться в файл-менеджере webhost? Разместите библиотеку у себя и пропишите там свои учётные данные от почты.

Comment: Вот здесь репозиторий библиотеки [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) и примеры использования